# adding rows to multiple HTML tables using JS

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm trying to add rows into several tables in HTML file using JS. There are 3 tables now.
When I try to click the "Add" button in each table, the row are added in all 3 tables but I only need to add a row in each table each time.
I just started to learn about HTML JQuery etc. would appreciate any advise given.
Thank you in advance!

This is how my JS and HTML file looks like:

```js
$(document.getElementById("table1")).ready(function() {
  $("#newrows").click(function() {
    var addcontrols = "<tr>"
    addcontrols += "<td><input type='text' name='jikan' placeholder='Enter time'></td>"
    addcontrols += "<td><input type='text' name='naiyou'></td>"
    addcontrols += "</tr>";
    $("table tbody").append(addcontrols);
  });
});

$(document.getElementById("table2")).ready(function() {
  $("#newrow").click(function() {
    var addcontrols1 = "<tr>"
    addcontrols1 += "<td><input type='text' name='jikan' placeholder='Enter time'></td>"
    addcontrols1 += "<td><input type='text' name='naiyou'></td>"
    addcontrols1 += "</tr>";
    $("table tbody").append(addcontrols1);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Today's Schedule<br>
</p>
<table border="1" id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>時間</th>
      <th>内容</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Add" id="newrows" style="width:500px" </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<p>
  Result Of The Day<br>
</p>
<table border="1" id="table2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>時間</th>
      <th>内容</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Add" id="newrow" style="width:500px" </td>

    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<p>
  Tomorrow's Schedule<br>
</p>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>時間</th>
      <th>内容</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Add" id="newrow" style="width:500px" </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<p>
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="送信">
```

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same id.  That's not valid HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code:

```
$(document.getElementById("table1")).ready(function() {
      $("#newrows").click(function() {
      var parentTable  = $(this).closest("table")
        var addcontrols = "<tr>"
        addcontrols += "<td><input type='text' name='jikan' placeholder='Enter time'></td>"
        addcontrols += "<td><input type='text' name='naiyou'></td>"
        addcontrols += "</tr>";
        parentTable.append(addcontrols);
      });
    });

    $(document.getElementById("table2")).ready(function() {
      $("#newrow").click(function() {
      var parentTable  = $(this).closest("table")
        var addcontrols1 = "<tr>"
        addcontrols1 += "<td><input type='text' name='jikan' placeholder='Enter time'></td>"
        addcontrols1 += "<td><input type='text' name='naiyou'></td>"
        addcontrols1 += "</tr>";
        parentTable.append(addcontrols1);
      });
    });
```

But It will be better if you can use common class instead of id. It ill be more clean and a simple block of code will do the task. Just use class="newrows" in each add button and use the following code. Example:

HTML :

```
<p>
  Today's Schedule<br>
</p>
<table border="1" id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>時間</th>
      <th>内容</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="button" class="newrows" value="Add" id="newrows" style="width:500px" </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<p>
  Result Of The Day<br>
</p>
<table border="1" id="table2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>時間</th>
      <th>内容</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="button" class="newrows" value="Add" id="newrow" style="width:500px" </td>

    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<p>
  Tomorrow's Schedule<br>
</p>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>時間</th>
      <th>内容</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Add" id="newrow" style="width:500px" </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<p>
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="送信">
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click",".newrows",function() {
    var parentTable  = $(this).closest("table")
    var addcontrols = "<tr>"
    addcontrols += "<td><input type='text' name='jikan' placeholder='Enter time'></td>"
    addcontrols += "<td><input type='text' name='naiyou'></td>"
    addcontrols += "</tr>";
    parentTable.append(addcontrols);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both functions into one and be more specific about where to append with something like this:

```
$(".newrow").click(function() { // class selector instead for reusability
    let addcontrols = "<tr>" // use let or const instead
    addcontrols += "<td><input type='text' name='jikan' placeholder='Enter time'></td>"
    addcontrols += "<td><input type='text' name='naiyou'></td>"
    addcontrols += "</tr>";

    $(this).closest("table").find("tbody").append(addcontrols); // $(this) is the clicked element
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you append on all the `table tbody` elements when the click occurs. You need to use DOM traversal to relate the clicked button to the target `tbody`. You can do that in this case by using `closest()` and `find()`.

You should also note that you syntax for the document.ready handler is incorrect, and there should only be one of them. Also you're using duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid. Group elements with common behaviour by class instead. Lastly, you're missing a closing `>` on the button element.

With all that said, try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  const addcontrols = '<tr><td><input type="text" name="jikan" placeholder="Enter time"></td><td><input type="text" name="naiyou"></td></tr>';
    
  $(".newrows").on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('table').find('tbody').append(addcontrols);
  });
});
```

```css
.newrows {
width:500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Today's Schedule<br>
</p>
<table border="1" id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>時間</th>
      <th>内容</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Add" class="newrows" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<p>
  Result Of The Day<br>
</p>
<table border="1" id="table2">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>時間</th>
      <th>内容</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Add" class="newrows" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<p>
  Tomorrow's Schedule<br>
</p>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>時間</th>
      <th>内容</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Add" class="newrows" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<p>
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="送信" />
</p>
```